# Windows Azure website custom domain no longer works

Tags: windows, azure

I have a portal hosted on windows Azure. I have configured a custom domain for the website. The domain has been working well, I could access it using the custom domain. Now the domain name is not working anymore. When I type it in the browser, the browser cannot find it. I get a server not found error on Firefox or a page cannot be displayed error on IE. The *_*_.azurewebsites.net URL is working fine but the custom one no longer works. Please help. The web role for the portal has shared mode configuration.

Comment: May it be the problem with the custom name DNS provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an A record or CNAME to enable the custom domain name for the Windows Azure hosted site?  There is a recent blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/21/a-records-cname-and-using-dns-with-windows-azure-web-sites-waws.aspx which does a decent job of explaining the options.  Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you @mcollier - We have had the custom domain name set up and we have been using the very same custom domain name to access the website for more than two months now. Since yesterday the domain name is no longer working.

Comment: Was it set up using an A record or CNAME?